# Running a python package

Tags: python, module, package, program-entry-point, python-2.6

Running Python 2.6.1 on OSX, will deploy to CentOS. Would like to have a package to be invoked from a command line like this:

```
python [-m] tst
```

For that, here is the directory structure made:

```
$PYTHONPATH/
    tst/
        __init__.py     # empty
        __main__.py     # below
        dep.py          # below
```

The following is in the files:

```
$ cat tst/__main__.py
from .dep import DepClass

print "Hello there"

$ cat tst/dep.py
class DepClass(object):
    pass

$
```

However, python gives me conflicting diagnostic:

```
$ python -m tst
/usr/bin/python: tst is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

OK, so it is recognized as a package. So I should be able to run it as a script? It has `__main__`...

```
$ python tst
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/runpy.py", line 121, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/runpy.py", line 34, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/Users/vdidenko/Code/emi/tst/__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .dep import DepClass
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

At this point I am lost. Why `non-package`? And how to structure the code then?

Comment: Not a dup, different responses when running with [-m], different solution. Even though sounds close. This problem failed to add `.__main__` when running, the other one did add it properly.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The feature to run the `__main__` module of a package when using the command line `-m` option was introduced in Python 2.7.  For 2.6 you need to specify the package module name to run; `-m test.__main__` should work.  See the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-unittest-discover-m).

Comment: Great, thank you! The docs in 2.6x were kinda vague and confusing between different versions did not help.

Comment: // , This is also a problem with statements like `python -m pip install argparse` and the like.