# What is `-m` stands for in `python -m unittest`?

Tags: python, python-unittest

What is `-m` stands for in `python -m unittest`? The unittest unit testing framework has other command line options like `-v -b -c -t` but wondering what does `-m` stands for? Is it part of unittest or other python command line option?

Comment: see on your own `python --help`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a python package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630822/running-a-python-package)

Comment: `-m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)` - from help

Answer (score 3):

if you run `python --help` you will see that:

```
-m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)
```

An explanation as to what that means and `-m` flage does can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319694/what-does-it-mean-to-run-library-module-as-a-script-with-the-m-option), I have copied the important parts below:

Properly designed modules usually do nothing except set up stuff (e.g. functions and types you could import), but they usually won’t have any visible side effect. That’s why you can do import sys and nothing happens.

However, some modules may offer useful stuff when they are run from the command line. Examples for that include venv but also http.server or idlelib: All of those are regular modules that can be imported from other modules without side effects.

But when executed directly, they all do things (e.g. venv sets up a virtual environment, http.server runs a simple HTTP server, and idlelib runs IDLE). This is usually done with the following check: