# I can't start the Parsing Shell for bllipparser

Tags: python, bllip-parser

I go to [The bllipparser website](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bllipparser/2015.12.3) and I follow the instruction to try to start the parsing shell as I want to visualize parse trees.  Well, when I try:

```
python -mbllipparser WSJ
```

I get

```
/usr/bin/python: bllipparser is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

So what's the deal, how can I start the parsing shell?

Comment: This seems to be an issue with Python 2.6 only. I've updated the PyPI info to clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake on the website.  You need

```
python -mbllipparser.ParsingShell WSJ
```

to start the shell successfully.  To find all of the contents of the bllipparser, one can refer to

[this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050120/execute-an-installed-python-package-as-a-script)