# How to make a package executable from the command line?

Tags: python, linux, chmod

I want to make a python package executable from the command line.

I know you can do `chmod +x myfile.py` where `myfile.py` starts with `#!/usr/bin/env` to make a single file executable using `./myfile.py`. I also know you can do `python -m mypackage` to run a package including a `__main__.py`.

However, if I add the shebang line to the `__main__.py` of a package, run `chmod +x mypackage`, and try `./mypackage`, I get the error `-bash: ./mypackage: Is a directory`.

Is it possible to run a package like this?

(To be clear, I'm **not** looking for something like py2exe to make it a standalone executable. I'm still expecting it to be interpreted, I just want to make the launch simpler)

Comment: You have to run a *file*, not a directory.  What happens with running ./mypackage/__main__.py ?  Python may know how to find the main program, but the Linux shell does not.

Comment: *Is it possible to run a package like this?* <= no. But why not drop a shell script?

Comment: You might want to look into the [setuptools `console_scripts` entry point](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-console-scripts-entry-point). *(Assuming your package is a proper `setuptools` distribution, containg a `setup.py` etc..)*

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630822/running-a-python-package and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050120/execute-an-installed-python-package-as-a-script `python -m module.__main__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is **No**.

When you make `chmod +x mypackage` you are doing nothing because `mypackage` is a directory and directories already has **execute** flag (or you will be unable to list their files). If you type: `ls -l` you will see.

Your options to run directly the whole package without installing it is the way you already mention: `python -m mypackage`, or make a shell script which will do that for you.

I see that your intentions are to execute just `./something` and your application to start working without specifying `python` in front and also this to not be globally installed. The easyest way will be to put a shell script that will launch your package.

Answer (score 0):

This contains what you are looking for. Walks you through how to setup your package so that a commandline application/interface is possible.

Would suggest using argparse instead of sys.argv. The post's comments are also helpful for more updated tips.

https://gehrcke.de/2014/02/distributing-a-python-command-line-application/

Comment: A link to an answer is not an answer; to be on-topic here, an answer needs to be complete enough to be helpful _even if all the links it contains break_.

Comment: See [Your answer is in another castle: When is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) on [meta.se].